# how to use supervisor when I should running a celery in django which is in a virtualenv?

Tags: django, celery, virtualenv, supervisord

Yesterday, I deployed a Django project with nginx, uwsgi, celery, supervisor. All seemed fine.

But I have some questions come about it.

Generally saying, this time i deployed a Django project and used the local python installation, but if i must use the python in a virtual environment, what should i do ?

For example, i code some task (with django-celery) which will be used by django site to control some timing task, and the django project based python3 (the python3 environment is in a virtualenv).

So the celery should be used by python3, which is in a virtualenv, not the local python environment.

It means that if i set the command in supervisor as:

```
command=python ****/manage.py celery
```

then an error would occur.

The uwsgi has some setting about this, where I can set the path of virtualenv.

But in supervisor, I could not see some setting or some way to use the virtualenv.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the path to your virtual environment in the command:

```
command=/path/to/venv/bin/python celery worker
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I would try like this .